# Total days between two dates by Month

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone suggest a VBA function to do the same? Return that in an array format would be useful so I can use that in other calculations. This is required for cash flow calculations through VBA.

Start Date - 01/Jan/2015
End Date - 05/Mar/2015

VBA Result

```
Count        Month        Month Days
1           1/Jan/2015    31
2           1/Feb/2015    28
3           1/Mar/2015     5
```

Note- If the supplied dates are wrong, then VBA has to assume default dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Function GetTable(startDate As Double, endDate As Double) As Variant
  Dim Table() As Variant, i As Long, y As Byte: i = 1: y = Day(startDate)
  If endDate <= startDate Then GetTable = "error": Exit Function
  ReDim Table(2, 0)
  Table(0, 0) = "Count"
  Table(1, 0) = "Month"
  Table(2, 0) = "Month Days"
  For startDate = startDate To endDate - 1
    If Month(startDate + 1) <> Month(startDate) Then
      ReDim Preserve Table(2, UBound(Table, 2) + 1)
      Table(0, UBound(Table, 2)) = UBound(Table, 2)
      If UBound(Table, 2) = 1 Then
        Table(1, UBound(Table, 2)) = y & Format(startDate, "/mmm/yyyy")
      Else
        Table(1, UBound(Table, 2)) = Format(startDate, "1/mmm/yyyy")
      End If
      Table(2, UBound(Table, 2)) = i
      i = 1
    Else
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve Table(2, UBound(Table, 2) + 1)
  Table(0, UBound(Table, 2)) = UBound(Table, 2)
  If UBound(Table, 2) = 1 Then
    Table(1, UBound(Table, 2)) = y & Format(startDate, "/mmm/yyyy")
  Else
    Table(1, UBound(Table, 2)) = Format(startDate, "1/mmm/yyyy")
  End If
  Table(2, UBound(Table, 2)) = i
  GetTable = Table
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks ....but when I run your above Function I get the result as below

Count        Month        Month Days
1           30/Jan/2015    31  (date shown as 30 Jan 2015 instead of 01 Jan 2015)
2           1/Feb/2015    28
3           1/Mar/2015     0   (instead of 5)

Comment: Convert your cells to text and then run it again... excel autoformates it... still... there is an error... ill solve it as soon as im home... also use transpose or it will be flipped (redim preserve only works with the last dimension)

Comment: Also if the first day is the 30th january it will show it corectly as the 30th... however: if you want it to be always 1/month/year, just say it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could do this:

Function to get # of days in a month:

```
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227538(v=vs.60).aspx
Function dhDaysInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Integer
    If dtmDate = 0 Then
        dtmDate = Date
    End If
    dhDaysInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 1) - _
     DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), Month(dtmDate), 1)
End Function
```

Function to populate array with required information

```
Function GetDateArray(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)

    Dim Holder() As Variant
    Dim i As Date, Count As Integer, temp As Integer

    my = Format(StartDate, "mm/yyyy")
    Count = 0

    ' pass 1 - find out how many months we encountered
    ' set up the array bounds accordingly
    For i = StartDate To EndDate
        ' each time month/year combination changes, we increment our count
        If Format(i, "mm/yyyy") <> my Then
            Count = Count + 1
            my = Format(i, "mm/yyyy")
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Holder(1 To Count + 1, 1 To 3)

    my = Format(StartDate, "mm/yyyy")
    Count = 0

    ' pass 2 - populate the array with information
    For i = StartDate To EndDate
        If Format(i, "mm/yyyy") <> my Then
            Count = Count + 1

            ' find days in the month
            temp = dhDaysInMonth(i - 1)
            If Count = 1 Then
                temp = temp - Format(StartDate, "dd") + 1
            End If

            ' populate array
            Holder(Count, 1) = Count
            Holder(Count, 2) = "01" & "/" & Format(i - 1, "mmm/yyyy")
            Holder(Count, 3) = temp

            ' reset mm/yyyy we remembered
            my = Format(i, "mm/yyyy")
        End If
    Next

    ' handle the last month's information
    Count = Count + 1
    temp = Format(EndDate, "dd")
    Holder(Count, 1) = Count
    Holder(Count, 2) = "01" & "/" & Format(i - 1, "mmm/yyyy")
    Holder(Count, 3) = temp

    GetDateArray = Holder

End Function
```

Test to make sure function returns what we need

```
Sub test()

    ' get data you desire
    Dim Holder() As Variant
    Holder = GetDateArray("2/27/2015", "5/5/2015")

    ' debug/print the array just as a proof
    Dim Row As Integer, Col As Integer, TempStr As String
    For Row = 1 To UBound(Holder, 1)
        TempStr = ""
        For Col = 1 To UBound(Holder, 2)
            TempStr = TempStr & Holder(Row, Col) & " | "
        Next
        Debug.Print TempStr
    Next

End Sub
```

Result (between 27th Feb and 5th May 2015):

```
1 | 01/Feb/2015 | 2 | 
2 | 01/Mar/2015 | 31 | 
3 | 01/Apr/2015 | 30 | 
4 | 01/May/2015 | 5 |
```